# Australian Telcos: Telstra vs. Boost

Tags: australia, mobile-operators, low-cost-carriers

I’m going to take a journey through the Australian bush (from Perth to Darwin then from Cairns to Sydney) and I need a SIM card for my phone. I have heard unanimously that Telstra is the best for these kind of trips but I have seen that Boost (https://boost.com.au/plans-2/) works with the Telstra network but is cheaper.

Does anyone knows if I can expect the same coverage from Telstra and Boost? 
What are the disadvantages of Boost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost indeed uses the Telstra 3G and 4G network.  However, Boost does not have access to the faster Telstra 4GX (700 MHz) network.

You can use the coverage maps provided by [Boost](https://boost.com.au/coverage-map/) and [Telstra](https://www.telstra.com.au/coverage-networks/our-coverage) to compare coverage.

You will notice from these maps that even though the Telstra network is regarded as the best in Australia, there are still **very significant areas where there is no coverage at all** for your itinerary.  You should consider bringing additional communications equipment (such as a EPIRB or a satellite phone) in case you become stranded in a remote area without mobile phone coverage.

Comment: I'm not even sure driving directly from Perth to Darwin is possible without it becoming a major overland expedition.  The closest would be Perth -> Newman -> Port Headland.  I suspect that the OP is taking the coast for both legs of his trip

Comment: Ok, Boost coverage is ridiculous in the outlands! Thank you for your suggestion but I'll follow the coast route which seems well covered.